# libpqxx : How to retrieve table name from the results container

Tags: c++, postgresql, libpqxx

I am trying to get table name ( or oid ) from postgresql using pqxx library. I know i can get it using `column_table()` if my result container is based on previous sql query command. However i am using insert,update or delete commands and i want to retrieve table name from the results after then. Can`t find a way how to do it .

```
....
const std::string _sqlcmd="update mytable set port=35012 where id=1";
pqxx::work Xaction(*m_conn);
m_result = Xaction.exec(_sqlcmd);
Xaction.commit();
```

`result.hxx` does not seem to cover such a function for commands like `insert` , `update` or `delete` functions.

Comment: I may misunderstand your intend but if you are updating a table you know the table name.

Comment: yes, obviously but this will be a library and client codes will send raw sql commands to the library. I have another option like parsing the sql command to see which table (s) are interested but instead i want to get it from pqxx containers. I , later will use table name in the postgresql notifications payloads.